# Determining the convex hull of the union of two polyhedra

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

I'm doing an introductory course to linear programming and I'm working through some exercises to prepare for the final exam, I'm stuck on an exercise and I would really appreciate a hint:

> Let $a\in \mathbb{R}^n $ where $\Vert a\Vert = \sqrt{a^T a}=1\,$ and let$\,\,b_1 , b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ with $b_1 < b_2$. Define $H_1=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n : a^Tx=b_1\}$ and $H_2=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n : a^Tx=b_2\}$
>
> Determine the convex hull of $H_1 \cup H_2$

The first thing I would do here is to define $C=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n : b_1 \leq a^Tx \leq b_2\}$, which is a polyhedron and therefore convex, and so $conv( H_1 \cup H_2) \subset C$.

$conv(S)$ here means the intersection of all convex sets that contain $S$.

I just need to show that $C \subset conv( H_1 \cup H_2)$, but I don't really know where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hesitate to call these polyhedra, but that's a minor point. You basically have the answer. However, you're never going to show that $C\subset(H_1\cup H_2)$, because $C$ has points that are in neither $H_1$ nor $H_2$. You need to show instead that $C\subset\mathop{\text{conv}}(H_1\cup H_2)$, and then that will give you $C=\mathop{\text{conv}}(H_1\cup H_2)$.

Comment: @JohnMoeller Whoops, that's what I meant. I don't really know where to start with the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $H_1$ and $H_2$ are hyperplanes, so what happens if you take any old halfspace $H'= \{x \mid (a')^T x \leq c \}$ for $a\neq a'$? Does $H'$ contain $H_1$ or $H_2$? Why or why not?

Comment: Hmm, if this was in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $H_1$ and $H_2$ would be lines, so in that case $H'$ could not contain $H_1$ or $H_2$, because any line that's not parallel with $a^Tx$ will intersect with $a^Tx$ at some point.

Comment: Bingo. Now just generalize it.

Comment: So if I define $C'=\{ b_1\leq (a')^Tx \leq b_2\}$ for $a' \neq a$, is the idea that this set cannot contain $H_1$ or $H_2$, and then C is the only option?

Comment: e.g. assume that $C$ is not a subset of $conv(H_1\cup H_2)$, then there is a set $C'\subset C$ which is a subset of $conv(H_1\cup H_2)$, but $C'$ must be like the $C'$ of the previous comment, and we have a contradiction.

Comment: That's the basic idea, yes.